# Microsoft Dynamics question

Tags: microsoft-dynamics

How can I get a free copy of "Microsoft Dynamics" to learn it at my home?

And how can I get started?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get 30 day trials at [Demos and Trials](http://www.microsoft.com/dynamics/en/us/demos-trials.aspx).  You can also get them if you have an MSDN subscription.  For getting started, check out the developer centers, like [Microsoft Dynamics AX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics/ax/default.aspx) -- each has a learning section with things like [How Do I Videos](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics/ax/cc507280.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the above link doesn't work anymore. Try using the below link
https://demos.microsoft.com/#/tenants

Answer (score 0):

You can download the DVD image for NAV 2009 SP1 and earlier from mibuso.com, which is one of the main user sites for Dynamics. It has a demo company in it.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Dynamics is a range of business products including:

ERP:
 - Microsoft Dynamics AX (former Axapta)
 - Microsoft Dynamics NAV (former Navision)
 - Microsoft Dynamics SL (former Solomon)
 - Microsoft Dynamics GP (former Great Plains)

CRM:
 - Microsoft Dynamics CRM

Use [Microsoft Download Center](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/default.aspx) to download trials. If you're working for a partner you may also download additional material from partnersource.